# How to check color-uniformity of a region?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I'm trying to check the homogeneity in pixel values over a small region in an image - e.g. A  word or a letter. However when taking the greyvalues of RGB, there is a lot of variance in values even between image patches that seem to have uniform color to the human eye.

Looking for a color-space that will be able to negate this variation if the difference in color is perceptually too little. Tried the L*a*b and HSV color spaces. They all work for a few cases, but often false colors come up in places of uniform color. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** (sample images from the ICDAR dataset. running tests on those)

[image: Hue channel from HSV]

[image: Original RGB image]

Comment: Can't you use quantized values of actual pixels to calculate histogram?

Comment: I usually have good luck loading my images into a python numpy array and doing measurements with the scipy.ndimage module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do some statistics on your pixels, and then find the correct thresholds for rejecting/accepting the image as uniformly colored.

**Step 0:**

Work with the appropriate colorspace. HSV and Lab are good. RGB is definitely bad.

**Step 1:**

Use a noise-resistant statistic. Calculate median value and interquantile range instead of average and mean square error. You may find some other statistic, that eliminates outliers. There are may ways (no one perfect) to find and eliminate a few outlier values in a distribution. `wiki robust statistics`

**Step 2:**

This is very app-specific. Find some images that are uniform, some that are not, apply your statistic on them and select the appropriate threshold. Do not expect to find something that always works. There will be some false positives/false negatives.

But you can tweak your threshold based on some a priori knowledge: Maybe it is ok to find some false negatives, but you don't want to miss a positive, so you move the threshold to the negatives, etc.

Comment: The robust statistics suggestion was really great. Not just for this particular problem, it makes a lot of sense to apply it to a whole bunch of other stuff. thanks.

Comment: One more thing -- the Hue component or HSV to be taken? And which component from Luv (definitely not L)? any thoughts/experience on that pls?

Comment: Hmm, it depend on what you want to accomplish. Color similarity, brightness similarity? Define your problem and the channel selection should be clear then...

Comment: color similarity. as invariant to lighting/brightness as possible.

Comment: Then it should be a combination on hue and saturation. measure the hue and the saturation, and if they are constant, your color is likely to be constant

Comment: wil do. and anything on L*a*b or L*u*v? Both a and b channels give a lot of fragmented things instead of solid color.